# Independence of two transformed variables from a symmetric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with a symmetric probability density function centered at zero. Let, $Y=|X|$ and $Z=\mathrm{sgn}(X)$, where $\mathrm{sgn}(X)=1$ if $X>0$ and $\mathrm{sgn}(X)=-1$ if $X\leq 0$. Are $Y$ and $Z$ independent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Since $X$ is symmetric, if $y\geq 0$ then
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y,Z=1)=\mathbb{P}(-y\leq X\leq y,X>0)=\mathbb{P}(0<X\leq y)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(-y\leq X\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)\mathbb{P}(Z=1)$$

because $\mathbb{P}(Z=1)=\mathbb{P}(X>0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y,Z=-1)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)\mathbb{P}(Z=-1)$ for all $y\geq 0$.

Since $Y$ only takes non-negative values and $Z$ only takes the values $\pm1$, this is enough to show that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Answer (score -1):

They are *almost everywhere* independent.

Due to symmetry of the distribution of $X$, knowing its sign does not tell you anything about its magnitude, nor vice versa, *except* at one fixed point: $0$.

When given that $~Y=0~$, then surely $~Z=0~$ and vice versa.

$$\operatorname {sgn}(X)=0 ~\iff~ \lvert X\rvert = 0$$

*Depending* on the distribution of $X$, this may be important, *or* it may be negligible.   (Ie: What is the probability measure of the event that $~X=0~$?)

Comment: But, here, sgn(X) = -1 if X=0.

Comment: "Almost everywhere independent" does not mean anything, random variables are independent or are not independent, period. In the present case, they are.